# Diacritics issue when retrieving data from a Filemaker database with DBI and ODBC

Tags: r, encoding, odbc, dbi

I am trying to switch from `RODBC`, which is depreciated, to `DBI`and `odbc` packages to retrieve data from a Filemaker database. It is configured to use UTF-8 encoding. I have configured `unixodbc` and using `isql` I am able to successfully retrieve data, including diacritics. For example, running `isql -v mydb myuid mypwd` and `select Contexte from Mobilier where ID_Objet = 1` returns `Dépôt`, which is correct (the terminal is also configured to use UTF-8).

However, when I am switching to R, things are getting more complicated. For example, consider the code below:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                   driver = "/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so",
                   database = "mydb", 
                   uid = "myuid", 
                   pwd = "mypwd",
                   host = "localhost")

val <- dbGetQuery(con, "select Contexte from Mobilier where ID_Objet = 1")

print(val)
  Contexte
1 D\u008ep\u0099t
```

With `RODBC`everything is working as expected:

```
library(RODBC)

con <- odbcConnect("mydb", uid = "myuid", pwd = "mypwd")

val <- sqlQuery(con, "select Contexte from Mobilier where ID_Objet = 1")

print(val)
  Contexte
1    Dépôt
```

`sessionInfo()` returns :

```
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.6.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Brussels
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-23

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.3    tools_4.3.3       rstudioapi_0.15.0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Following r2evans comment, I tried inserting some text in my database using `RODBC` and retrieving it with `DBI`:

```
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con1 <- RODBC::odbcConnect("mydb", uid = "myuid", pwd = "mypwd")
con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  driver = "/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so",
                  database = "mydb",
                  uid = "myuid",
                  pwd = "mypwd",
                  host = "localhost")

# Data with diacritics to be inserted using RODBC
insert <- data.frame("ID_Objet" = 5000,
                     "Contexte" = "Dépôt")

# The encoding is right
Encoding(insert$Contexte)
> [1] "UTF-8"

# Inserting the data with RODBC...
RODBC::sqlSave(con1, insert)

# ...and retrieving it
x <- RODBC::sqlQuery(con1, "select * from insert")

# Diacritics are alright but not the encoding...
x$Contexte
> [1] "Dépôt"
Encoding(x$Contexte)
> [1] "unknown"

# Reading now the same data with DBI and odbc
y <- DBI::dbReadTable(con2, "insert")

# Diacritcs are gone but the original encoding is detected
y$Contexte
> [1] "D\u008ep\u0099t"
Encoding(y$Contexte)
>[1] "UTF-8"
```

Comment: The value you are getting is not UTF-8 encoded. It appears to be [Mac OS Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) encoding. Are you sure the Filemaker data is using UTF-8? How did you verify that? Is this all happening on the same Mac?

Comment: As I am using location names from all over Europe with all kind of diacritics, my database is using UTF-8. However, if I specify Mac Roman as the enconding in the ```dbconnect```function I get some accents right, but others are replaced by "?". Specifying "UTF-8 doesn't solve my issue. By the way, I have no problem at all with RODBC: all my diacritics are there in UTF-8. I will stick to it for the moment I guess.

Comment: Just because you are using text that has diacritics doesn’t mean that you are using UTF-8 a lot of other encodings allow those same characters. It’s really hard to know exactly what’s going without a reproducible example.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `sessionInfo()` or at least  `Sys.getlocale()`.

Comment: I updated my question, however it's very difficult to provide a reproducible example without sharing my database. Also the ODBC driver is platform dependent, which is not making things easier.

Comment: I don't think that the ODBC driver itself has anything to do with this, since both the `RODBC` and `DBI`+`odbc` code should be going through the same ODBC driver. One difference between the two is that `RODBC` is using its internal [`RODBC.c`](https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/src/RODBC.c) code, whereas `odbc` is using the `nanodbc` linked library. I suggest that to make this reproducible, perhaps you can programmatically create a table (just 1 row, inserted using `RODBC` mechanics) and then test querying it with both packages. Does that make sense?

Comment: What does `Encoding(val)` return for each?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I added a code inserting UTF-8 text in my database using ```RODBC``` and retrieving it with ```RODBC``` and ```DBI```. The first keeps the diacritics but the enconding is unknown. The other fails but the enconding is still UTF-8...